# How to get the collection of features (geometries and metadata) after loading a GPX file as vector source in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to load a set of waypoints (which constitute a track) from a GPX file and have them rendered on a map as "Point" geometries. Then I intend to link them together with a line (I assume this will be "LineString" geometry). When clicking on any of the waypoints, the waypoint metadata (within the "cmt" tag in the GPX file) needs to be overlayed on the map.

I'm stuck as it appears the collection of features in my source is empty:
vector.getProperties().source.getFeatures() returns an empty array.
*What I'm missing?*

In the [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/gpx.html) I've seen it seems than whenever the data source is loaded, the features become seamlessly accessible (see below the style property with the inline function setting the style).

```
var vector = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
          url: 'data/gpx/fells_loop.gpx',
          format: new GPX()
        }),
        style: function(feature) {
          return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
        }
      });
```

To be honest, I do not understand how GPX data (features) become seamlessly accessible (as suggested by the Openlayers GPX example)...this is probably another question though...

The GPX file I'm trying to load is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1" 
creator="Voyage Recorder Converter - www.yachtd.com"
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"><metadata><time>2019-03-17T09:39:29.988Z</time></metadata>
<wpt lat="36.204621700" lon="29.630329200"><name>2019-03-17 09:41:30.684</name><ele>-18.03</ele>
<cmt>TWS 5.29 knots (med 5.09, avg 4.87, min 2.49, max 5.79)
TWD 283.68 degrees (med 292.05, avg 292.99, min 283.68, max 316.18)
TWA 213.66 degrees (med 213.12, avg 208.58, min 178.45, max 213.66)
</cmt>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="36.204555700" lon="29.630280100"><name>2019-03-17 09:43:31.428</name><ele>-18.03</ele>
<cmt>TWS 3.50 knots (med 3.79, avg 3.66, min 1.09, max 5.60)
TWD 248.08 degrees (med 281.99, avg 281.00, min 248.08, max 306.77)
TWA 139.65 degrees (med 162.43, avg 163.79, min 139.65, max 203.54)
</cmt>
</wpt>...
```

and the code is as follows (note that I'm centering the map to the coordinates of the first waypoint)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        .map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 800px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>

    <title>OpenLayers example</title>

</head>

<body>

<h2>My Map</h2>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">


    const topoMap = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
            url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer'
        })
    });

    const baseOSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    const view = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([29.630329200, 36.204621700]),
        zoom: 6
    });

    const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: './test.gpx',
            format: new ol.format.GPX()
        })
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [ baseOSM, topoMap, vector ],
        view: view
    });

    console.log('center: ' + view.getCenter());
    console.log(vector);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I took a copy of your code and data (terminated it with `</gpx>`) and the first two waypoints show correctly in the harbour (as separate features after zooming to level 20).  Is your url path correct?

Comment: Thanks for this Mike... it made me think. I was not using a development server, just trying to make it work opening a local file. As soon as I executed in the development server it worked... rookie mistake...